# Swift - Convert an Image's Data to Binary Number

Tags: swift, string, encoding, binary

Is it possible to take an image and convert its data to Binary?

I ***was*** able to convert an image's data to a **String**, but I'm not sure how to now take that String and display its Binary equivalent.

For that matter, if I type in a word - *any* word, like for example "Hello", I'd like the App to display the FIVE binary numbers that make it up:
-the first number would be the binary number (or binary code) for the letter "H"
-the second number would be the binary number for the letter "e"
-the third number would be the binary number for the letter "l"

etc.

Comment: Do you know how to convert a single number to binary? What format do you want the binary value? As a string? Why do you want this?

Comment: Try reading "Accessing a String’s Unicode Representation" in the [documentation for `String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string), in particular the subsection "UTF-8 View". HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `binary data` from a `String` like,

```
let str = "hello"
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
```

In case you want to get the binary data in the form of 0/1, you can use,

```
data?.forEach({ print(String($0, radix: 2)) })
```

The above code prints the `binary numbers` corresponding to each `byte` in `data`.

**Edit:**

To get `8 characters` long `binary numbers`, you just need to `append extra 0s` to the start of the `string`, i.e.

```
let binaryArr = data?.map({(byte) -> String in
    var str = String(byte, radix: 2)
    let countToAppend = 8 - str.count
    let extraZerosStr = ([String](repeating: "0", count: countToAppend)).joined()
    str = extraZerosStr + str
    return str
})

print(binaryArr) //for "Hello", it prints ["01001000", "01100101", "01101100", "01101100", "01101111"]
```

Comment: Hey this seems to work almost perfectly - except that its outputting a different number of 0's and 1's for different types of inputs. For example, when I enter "1" it outputs *six* characters: "110001", but when I enter "A" it outputs *seven* characters: "1000001".  What I was expecting is to always get an *eight* character long Binary number - like you do here: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/convert-text-to-binary/

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: That's it - perfect! Thank you Sir :-)